# Has many :through association not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, model-associations

I have two models that can have tags added to them.

- Player
- Ticket

and I have a `Tag` model which belongs to both so I have two join models

- tag_ticket
- tag_player

I am getting a `Could not find the association :tag_tickets in model Ticket` error but my association is in there.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_tickets
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_tickets
end
```

I'm just focusing on the `Ticket` model but the player model should look similar.

this is my migration for `TagTicket`

```
class CreateTagTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tag_tickets do |t|
      t.integer :ticket_id
      t.integer :tag_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the :tag_tickets join first like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_tickets
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_tickets
end
```

You would also need to specify the joins in your `TagTicket` model:

```
class TagTicket < ActiveRecored::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Alternatively, you can skip all this and use a habtm join (only recommended if the tag_tickets join is truly *only* used as a join and has no primary key for itself).  In this case you would have no TagTicket model (just a tag_tickets table) and the Ticket model would look like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

Comment: I've tried the top option before but I get this `Could not find the source association(s) :tag or :tags in model TagTicket. Try 'has_many :tags, :through => :tag_tickets, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?`

Comment: Thanks, the middle section helped. the rails error only complained about the `Ticket` half of the problem :)